# some print question about python selenium with thread

Tags: python, selenium

I am coding a python use selenium to auto click the button

Here is my example code and it is using 4 thread webdriver

```
    while (i < max_click + 1):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("blahblahblah").click()
    sleep(10)
    i = i + 1
    print(i*number_of_threads)
```

output

```
4
4
4
4
8
8
8
8
```

how can I let it print once and the count is accumulation?